# wxPython: Getting values from Dialog, and using it outside the Dialog class

Tags: wxpython

I have this simple Dialog:

```
import wx  
import wx.lib.sized_controls as sc  
import time  
import datetime  
class Dialog(sc.SizedDialog):  
    def __init__(self, parent, id):  
        sc.SizedDialog.__init__(self, None, -1, "AuTel", style=wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE | wx.RESIZE_BORDER)            
        pane = self.GetContentsPane()  
        pane.SetSizerType("form")  

        wx.StaticText(pane, -1, "N1:")
        N1_BOX = wx.SpinCtrl(pane, -1, "", (40,40), (60,-1))
        N1_BOX.SetRange(1,1000)
        N1_BOX.SetValue(2)

        wx.StaticText(pane, -1, "N2:")
        N2_BOX = wx.SpinCtrl(pane, -1, "", (40,40), (60,-1))
        N2_BOX.SetRange(1,1000)
        N2_BOX.SetValue(10)

        wx.StaticText(pane, -1, "T1:")
        T1_BOX = wx.SpinCtrl(pane, -1, "", (40,40), (60,-1))
        T1_BOX.SetRange(1,60)
        T1_BOX.SetValue(4)

        wx.StaticText(pane, -1, "T2:")
        T2_BOX = wx.SpinCtrl(pane, -1, "", (40,40), (60,-1))
        T2_BOX.SetRange(1,60)
        T2_BOX.SetValue(5)

        RUN_BUTTON = self.SetButtonSizer(self.CreateStdDialogButtonSizer(wx.OK | wx.CANCEL))

        self.Fit()
        self.SetMinSize(self.GetSize())

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
dlg = Dialog(None, -1)
dlgrslt = dlg.ShowModal()

if dlgrslt != wx.ID_OK:
print ('Exiting..')
exit
else:
    pass
    print (N1+N2/T1-T2)

dlg.Destroy()
app.MainLoop()
```

I need when I click OK, Values of N1_BOX, N2_BOX, T1_BOX, and T2_BOX to be taken, then I can use them later in the script for other purpose. What shall I do in my script in order to achieve this ? Also, how can I make another Window to display the result of N1+N2/T1-T2 ? I need this window to be attached with the dialog window, but i don't know how can I do it.
Sorry for my basic questions, but I am new to programing world.

Regards,
Amr

Answer (score 4):

1: Accessing input values

The most basic way is to make each 'box' a member of your class.

i.e. wherever you write N1_BOX, put 'self.N1_BOX'.

So, in your calling code, you can access dlg.N1_BOX.GetValue()

```
valX = dlg.N1_BOX.GetValue()+dlg.N2_BOX.GetValue() / dlg.T1_BOX.GetValue()+dlg.T2_BOX.GetValue()
print valX
```

2: The 'result dialog':

Create a second class, say ResultDialog, with an extra parameter in the **init** method.
You can then pass in your new value into this extra parameter.

So, say you had set the valX variable, then you can pass it in like so:

```
dlg2= ResultDialog(None,-1,str(valX))
```

Note the use of str() to convert the valX number for presentation on a label. This could  be done inside the init method, but I put it here as a hint.

HTH